# JSON-LD normalization - ignore JSON nesting

Tags: geojson, json-ld

I'm working on JSON-LD serialization, and ideally I would like to have a `@context` which I can add to the existing GeoJSON output (together with some `@id`s and `@type`s), so that both the Turtle output and the JSON-LD output will normalize to the same triples.

Data is organized as follows: each object/feature has an ID and a name, and data on one or more layers. Per layer, there is a data field, which contains a JSON object.

Example GeoJSON output:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",   
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "admr.nl.appingedam",
        "name": "Appingedam",
        "layers": {
          "cbs": {
              "data": {
              "name": "Appingedam",
              "population": 1092
            }
          },
          "admr": {
              "data": {
              "name": "Appingedam",
                "gme_code": 4654,
                "admn_level": 3
              }
          }
        }
      },
      "geometry": {…}
    }
  ]
}
```

Example Turtle output:

```
<admr.nl.appingedam>
    a :Node ;
    dc:title "Appingedam" ;
    :createdOnLayer <layer/admr> ;
    :layerData <admr.nl.appingedam/admr> ;
    :layerData <admr.nl.appingedam/cbs> .
<admr.nl.appingedam/admr>
    a :LayerData ;
    :definedOnLayer <layer/admr> ;
    <layer/admr/name> "Appingedam" ;
    <layer/admr/gme_code> "4654" .
    <layer/admr/admn_level> "3" .
<admr.nl.appingedam/cbs>
    a :LayerData ;
    :definedOnLayer <layer/cbs> ;
    <layer/cbs/name> "Appingedam" ;
    <layer/cbs/population> "1092" ;
```

The properties object does not have its own URI. Is there a way to create a JSON-LD context which takes the contents of the properties into account, but further 'ignores' its precence?

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Gregg Kellogg on [JSON-LD mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-linked-json/2014Mar/0018.html):

> This is something that keeps coming up: having a transparent layer,
>   that basically folds properties up a level. This was discussed during
>   the development of JSON-LD, but ultimately it was rejected.
>
> I don't see any prospects for doing something in the short-term, but
>   it could be revisited in a possible future WG chartered with revising
>   the spec. Feedback like this is quite useful.
>
> In the mean time, you can play with different JSON-LD encodings that
>   match your RDF though tools like http://json-ld.org/playground and my
>   own http://rdf.greggkellogg.net/distiller.
>
> Gregg